# Doing a large number of upserts as fast as possible

Tags: mysql, performance, upsert

My app (which uses MySQL) is doing a large number of subsequent upserts. Right now my SQL looks like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer (name,customer_number,social_security_number,phone) VALUES ('VICTOR H KINDELL','123','123','123')
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer (name,customer_number,social_security_number,phone) VALUES ('VICTOR H KINDELL','123','123','123')
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer (name,customer_number,social_security_number,phone) VALUES ('VICTOR H KINDELL OR','123','123','123')
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer (name,customer_number,social_security_number,phone) VALUES ('TRACY L WALTER PERSONAL REP FOR','123','123','123')
INSERT IGNORE INTO customer (name,customer_number,social_security_number,phone) VALUES ('TRACY L WALTER PERSONAL REP FOR','123','123','123')
```

So far I've found `INSERT IGNORE` to be the fastest way to achieve upserts. Selecting a record to see if it exists and then either updating it or inserting a new one is too slow. Even this is not as fast as I'd like because I need to do a separate statement for each record. Sometimes I'll have around 50,000 of these statements in a row.

Is there a way to take care of all of these in just one statement, without deleting any existing records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put everything in 1 insert
`INSERT IGNORE INTO table_1 (field1, field2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'), etc`. You may also want to check `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you need to either updater or insert a record.

Comment: If I use `INSERT IGNORE` like that, wouldn't it ignore the whole query if even just one of the records existed? Unfortunately I can't use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for reasons that would require a lengthy explanation.

Comment: `If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.`

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` is also an option, but since it deletes and replaces existing rows it's likely to be less efficient than `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: @Jason Swett. It will behave exactly the same as a number of `INSERT IGNORE`. The records that already exist will be ignored, others will be inserted.